# Mvc2 validation summary and required metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

[source code](http://drop.io/noig7g3/asset/mvcapplication3-rar)...

Thing is, if i specify required metadata using fluent modelmetadata provider like this=>

```
public class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooModelMetadataConfiguration : ModelMetadataConfiguration<Foo>
    {
        public FooModelMetadataConfiguration()
        {
            Configure(x => x.Bar)
                .Required("lapsa") ;
        }
    }
```

And write this into my view =>

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Bar) %>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

And add this to home controller =>

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Foo foo)
 {
       ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

       return View(foo);
 }
```

It will output this html =>

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
  <ul>
    <li>lapsa</li>
    <li>The Bar field is required.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can't understand why 2nd error is rendered and how to omit it.

Author of System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility framework replied with =>

> I think this is a known issue of asp.net mvc, i could not remember the exact location where I have read it, I suggest you post the issue in asp.net mvc issue tracker over codeplex.

But before i post anything on issue tracker - i would like to understand first what exactly is wrong.

Any help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [fixed](http://github.com/kazimanzurrashid/AspNetMvcExtensibility/issues/closed#issue/2) now.